# How do you calculate total current draw in parallel?

Tags: current, parallel, fan, peltier

If I have a 12V power supply, a 6A TEC, and a 0.15A fan running in parallel, how do I calculate total current draw?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are putting them in parallel and connecting them to 12 V, the current through each will be whatever it would be if connected alone, 3 to 6 A for the TEC, and 0.15 A for the fan. The total  current would be the two individual currents added together, so 3.15 A to 6.15 A.

Comment: So if a fan recommends 0.15A, I don’t necessarily need a resistor because it will only draw 0.15A?

Comment: @ThatProgrammerJack Yes, the current rating is what the fan will draw when connected to the correct voltage for it. You just need to make sure the supply has enough capacity to handle whatever load you're putting on it. If your total load is up to 6.15 A you would need a supply that could provide that, plus a bit of a safety factor, maybe 20%. An 8 A supply should do it, unless your load has a large surge current, then you might need more.

Comment: thank you for the answers.

Comment: So if the fan is drawing 0.15A, any components in series after the fan would be restricted to 0.15A? For example, could I have a low-current LED after the fan, but not, for example, after the TEC because the current would be too high?

Comment: @ThatProgrammerJack you should not put other components in series with the fan because that will change the voltage across the fan to something different than what it was designed for.

Comment: @ThePhoton Well would it be fine to use a resistor to decrease the current draw of the TEC so as not to burn it out?

Comment: @ThatProgrammerJack yes putting a resistor in series with the TEC will decrease the current flowing through the TEC - but whatever current is flowing through the TEC is also flowing through the resistor, and current through a resistor will tend to make the resistor heat up...

Comment: @brhans yeah I realized that a 1 ohm resistor would be taking 4 amps with a voltage drop of 4 volts so I would need a 16 WATT resistor xD I realized I don’t necessarily need to stay under the TEC’s Qmax, just the Imax and Vmax and it should be fine.